# how to check if a character is equal to double quote in java

Tags: java, char, double-quotes

I want to check the value of a char to see if it is double quote or not in Java. How can I do it?

Answer (score 13):

```
if (myChar == '"') { // single quote, then double quote, then single quote
    System.out.println("It's a double quote");
}
```

If you want to compare a String with another one, and test if the other string only contains the double quote char, then you must escape the double quote with a \ :

```
if ("\"".equals(myString)) {
    System.out.println("myString only contains a double quote char");
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to check whether a single or double quote is opening or ending a string?

Answer (score 7):

If you are dealing with a `char` then simply do this:

```
 c == '"';
```

If c is equal to the double quote the expression will evaluate to `true`.

So, you can do something like this:

```
if(c == '"'){
  //it is equal
}else{
  //it is not
}
```

On the other hand, if you don't have a `char` variable, but a `String` object instead, you have to use `equals` method and the escape character `\` like this:

```
if(c.equals("\"")){
  //it is equal
}else{
  //it is not
}
```

Answer (score 5):

For checking double quote is present in a string, following code can be used.
Double quote have 3 different possible ascii values.

```
if(testString.indexOf(8220)>-1 || testString.indexOf(8221)>-1 ||
     testString.indexOf(34)>-1)
   return true;
else 
   return false;
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case what I do is, if you want to compare, for example, a server response that should be `"OK"`, then:

```
if (serverResponse.equals("\"OK\"")) {
...
}
```